# how to install ubuntu on a computer without using a monitor?

Tags: boot, networking, system-installation, ssh, monitor

**I have a computer but with no available screen**, how can I install Ubuntu server on it using a laptop I have, I can't format the hard drive in another computer and buying a new monitor is not an option for me can you guys tell how can I do that?

The computer is pentium 4; 80 GB HDD; 800 MB ram; with external wifi adapter.

I think using ssh or network boot or something like that would be the way to do it, I'm not sure.